# How to get CodeDeploy event logs even when they are successful?

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, stdout, aws-code-deploy

I work on a deployment process using AWS CodeDeploy. When there is a failure in one of the scripts specified in appspec.yml, you get this nice little log output giving back STDOUT:

[image]

However, when all events are successful, it seems there is no way to see STDOUT:

[image]

Is there a way to see all STDOUT even when deployment events succeed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Someone managed to get the answer to this and here is the solution:

On each instance:

```
cat /opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/deployment-logs/codedeploy-agent-deployments.log
```

Sorry for the bother, hope it helps somebody one day!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to see deployment logs is to set up your instances to upload them to CloudWatch logs. See instructions [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/view-aws-codedeploy-logs-in-amazon-cloudwatch-console/).

Otherwise, you can view the log data by ssh-ing to the hosts. See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/deployments-view-logs.html) for more details.